# JavaFX: Disable all components while a process is running and show progress indicator

Tags: java, javafx, progress, progress-indicator

I have a method that read values from the the database and returns a `Map<Integer,String>.` This method takes some time to return the map.

Till the time values are getting read I want a progress indicator(only loading ring like indicator will be enough,no need for progress bar) to be displayed on screen and all other components should be disabled till the time progress bar is shown.

```
public void scanDevice() {
    ObservableList<TextField> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(vehicleId, vehicleName, deviceType,
            offboardBroker1, offboardBroker2, postfixQueue, pKIServer);
    editedValuesMap.clear();
    // devicePlugged = true;
    if (cbChooseProject.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
        try {
            devicePlugged = dsAdapter.getAdapter();
            if (devicePlugged) {
                if (bScanDevice.isFocused()) {
                    readMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                    //Process Start
                    readMap = dsAdapter.initScan();
                    //Process End

                    if (!readMap.isEmpty() && readMap != null) {
                        isWritten = true;
                        isDeviceSideEnabled();
                        editDeviceContents.setDisable(false);
                        vehicleId.setText(readMap.get(0));
                        vehicleName.setText(readMap.get(1));
                        deviceType.setText(readMap.get(2));
                        offboardBroker1.setText(readMap.get(3));
                        offboardBroker2.setText(readMap.get(4));
                        postfixQueue.setText(readMap.get(5));
                        pKIServer.setText(readMap.get(6));
                        lContentsSerialNo.setText(readMap.get(7));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disabled all nodes with a method like the following but if you are also wanting to wait while something is happening an overlay using `StackPane`s may be the preferred choice.

```
public void setNodesDiabled(boolean disable, Node... nodes) {
    for(Node node : nodes) {
        node.setDisable(disable);
    }
}
```

With an arbitrary node count, you can disable and re-enable as many nodes that are relevant to the process. It also helps to clean up as you won't have several `node.setDisable(true); node2.setDisable(true);` and so on.

Here in this example you won't need `setNodesDisabled()` because the StackPane overlay prevents clicking anything other than what's inside it. The background color is gray with 70% alpha so that you can tell it's an overlay.

```
public class ProgressExample extends Application {

    public StackPane layout, main, progress;

    public StackPane createProgressPane() {
        ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        indicator.setMaxHeight(50);
        indicator.setMaxWidth(50);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(160,160,160,0.7)");
        pane.getChildren().add(indicator);

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // Your process here.
                // Any changes to UI components must be inside Platform.runLater() or else it will hang.
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    layout.getChildren().remove(pane);
                });
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
        return pane;
    }

    public StackPane createMainPane() {
        Label label = new Label("Hello World!");
        label.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD, 16));

        Button start = new Button("Start Process");
        start.setOnAction(action -> {
            progress = createProgressPane();
            layout.getChildren().add(progress);
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, start);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(vbox);
        return pane;
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        main = createMainPane();

        layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(main);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 900, 550);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Progress Example");
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

I believe the problem is that you are trying to change the values of `TextField`s inside the `Task` which is not the FX application thread which is why you are getting `Not on FX application thread`. To fix this you need to put your lines that modify nodes inside a `Platform.runLater()` like the following to your if statement.

```
if (readMap != null && !readMap.isEmpty()) { // Swap the order, can't check empty if it's null.
    isWritten = true;
    isDeviceSideEnabled();
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        editDeviceContents.setDisable(false);
        vehicleId.setText(readMap.get(0));
        vehicleName.setText(readMap.get(1));
        deviceType.setText(readMap.get(2));
        offboardBroker1.setText(readMap.get(3));
        offboardBroker2.setText(readMap.get(4));
        postfixQueue.setText(readMap.get(5));
        pKIServer.setText(readMap.get(6));
        lContentsSerialNo.setText(readMap.get(7));
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me whats the use of this  Thread.sleep(2000);
Do i need to calculate the time required by my method and then sleep the thread for that time and due to project containts I have to use BorderPane Layout.
I am getting the below error:
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5

Comment: The use of `Thread.sleep(2000);` in the example was simply because it's an example. Without anything inside to take time the progress pane wouldn't be visible long enough while testing it out. You don't need it. As for the error, could you edit the question to include those lines within the `Task`? You need to put your lines that change FX nodes and panes within their own `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: Mathews, I have added the code that contains my process. The process read values from a device a displays it on UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

It uses a [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) that can be started more than once. It is not completebut something to start with.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        Service<Void> serv = new Service<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        int maxWork = 10;
                        for (int i = 0; i < maxWork; i++) {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            updateProgress(i + 1, maxWork);
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void succeeded() {
                        super.succeeded();
                        updateProgress(1, 1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void cancelled() {
                        super.cancelled();
                        updateProgress(1, 1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void failed() {
                        super.failed();
                        updateProgress(1, 1);
                    }

                };
            }
        };

        ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
        pi.progressProperty().bind(serv.progressProperty());
        

        Button bStart = new Button("Start");
        bStart.setOnAction(e -> {
            serv.reset();
            serv.start();
        });

        root.setCenter(bStart);
        root.setBottom(pi);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        pi.getScene().getRoot().disableProperty().bind(serv.runningProperty());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In CSS I added:

```
.progress-indicator:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1;
}
```